# java: xpath expression with namespace

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm trying to extract an portion of xml using this code:

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(responseStream);

XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//[local-name()='UpdateResponseDocument']");
```

As you can see, I'm using `local-name`.

I'm getting this exception:

> Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token.

My xml is:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns2:cercarInformacioPacientResponseV2 xmlns:ns2="http://salut.gencat.cat/hc3/etccerques" xmlns:ns3="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:ns4="http://principal.agenda.consulta.ws.hc3.salut.cat/">
      <ns2:UpdateResponseDocument>
        <idMissatge>123456789
        </idMissatge>
        <resultCode>OK
        </resultCode>
        <result>
          <executionCode>ETC_OIP_000
          </executionCode>
          <executionDetails>El procés s'ha dut a terme correctament.
          </executionDetails>
          <pacient>
            ...
          </pacient>
        </result>
      </ns2:UpdateResponseDocument>
    </ns2:cercarInformacioPacientResponseV2>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
"//[local-name()='UpdateResponseDocument']"
```

with

```
"//*[local-name()='UpdateResponseDocument']"
```

Note asterisk `*` which stands for *any element node*